# How can I limit the display of columns on Excel?

Tags: excel

I would like to create an Excel document with all the date from 01-01-2018 to 31-12-2018 with each day in a separate columns but only display a certain amount of days (not the entire year) with the possibility to scroll left or right to see the rest. What can I do to achieve this ?

I've tried to to freeze the panes but it's not what I want.

What I have :

[image]

What I would like (with a scroll bar) :

[image]

Comment: Is this something that you can already do via the UI, and you are asking how to do it with a program? In that case, use the Macro Recorder, do this via the UI, and see which methods and properties are used to make it happen. Or are you looking to do this with VBA code? In that case, you should include in your question what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can only freeze one side of the table, and even if you use the Split button to try to hold the other side still, it turns off the freeze, so you can't do both at once (which would have solved it).

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-panes-to-lock-rows-or-columns-in-separate-worksheet-areas-516a7001-b3ed-4122-a6bb-fd6d4a9d6434

[image: split button]

If you turn the spreadsheet sideways, so the dates go down the page instead of across, you may be able to do something with the Group button:

[image: group button]

Sorry but I don't think there is a way to solve it properly, maybe you can move the static columns from the right over to the left too?